# is this bad to put a do-loop in another do-loop?

Tags: java, android, performance

is this bad for performance that we put a do-loop in another do-loop?

both of loops are in a timer, is this bad practice?

```
Timer gamingTimer = new Timer();

        gamingTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        int board = 0;
                        do {

                            int loop = 0;
                            do {

                                log("thx for answering me <3");

                                loop++;
                            } while (loop < 7);

                            board++;
                        } while (board < 5);

                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: The general answer is: "it depends".  And in your specific example the answer would be "it doesn't matter", and "don't waste your time with premature optimization".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having nested loops is actually very common in programming in general and it does not necessarily indicate bad performance.

In your specific example, the nested loops have a constant running time, so it does not matter at all.

If your loops would depend on some other variable (i.e. something like `loop < max` and `board < max`), the running would be affected quadratically by that variable because the inner loop runs through all its iterations for every iteration of the outer loop. Depending on the upper limit of `max`, the performance could be impacted more or less.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing premature optimization. You won't get a definitive answer for that question.

Do a performance test yourself to see if what you're doing is bad or not.

But it's not bad to do nested loop unless there's another way to do it.